# Trying to filter the single column without disturbing the rest of

Tags: excel, vba

I just want to filter the single column without disturbing the rest of columns i have been using below code but it is not applying on sheet.

Which is giving an error can someone please help me to do this.

I also wants to filter it Large to smallest values just single column.

Any help over the problem will be greatly appreciated.

```
        Sub Filter()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Put your sheet name inside the quotes
With ws
  If Not .AutoFilterMode Then .Range("B1:B").AutoFilter
     .Range("B").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">100"
     .AutoFilterMode = False
     .Range("B").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<5000"
     .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Range("A1:A")` is not a valid range specification

Comment: Do you even understand your posted Code and what it does? What Error Message do you get?

Comment: Method range of object _worksheet failed. That error is comes.

Comment: Yes i changed the column reference.

Comment: And do you stil have a problem?

Comment: FaneDuru, Yes Sir, I changed the code as mentioned above from range A to B

Comment: The column is not the issue. The syntax is wrong.
Try:
    .Range("A:A")

Comment: MrDogme, Sir i did it but issue is still same .Range("B:B").AutoFilter

Comment: What exactly do you even mean by that? In Excel, when you **filter** a column, the rows that are excluded are hidden.  Excel cannot hide only a part of a row, so, with filtering, there is no way to do that without *disturbing the rest of columns*.  Providing an example of your data, and what you expect for a result, might be helpful.

Comment: It looks like the title of our question may have been truncated. It would also be helpful to provide examples of some simple input and the resulting expected output after applying your filtering since it's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoFilter can't do what you want.  It hides entire rows so the other columns **will** be disturbed.
Say we start with:

[image]

and apply a filter to column **B** with:

```
Sub ShSh()
Dim B As Range
Set B = Range("B:B")

B.AutoFilter
B.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">100", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<5000"
End Sub
```

We get:

[image]

As you see, Column **A** gets "disturbed".  The data in the hidden rows is not changed; it just is not visible.

**EDIT#1:**

This code will clear column **B** cells that do not meet the criteria:

```
Sub DataCleaner()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        v = Cells(i, "B").Value
        If v > 100 And v < 5000 Then
        Else
            Cells(i, "B") = ""
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Gary's Student, Sir thank you so much for the help. But the issue is that it hides the rows of other columns, its sorting should be for Current column not for all columns. B columns values should be adjusted just.

Comment: @ShSh: No offence, but it looks you do not understand what you are doing...

Comment: @FaneDuru  I present a super-simple demo.  If the Poster can duplicate my example, they can later tailor it to their specific needs.

Comment: But, since **filtering means altering/hiding rows**, how to explain what is it about "Colum B values should be adjusted just" in a logical context? But let us be nice in the Christmas spirit...  He maybe would need the move somewhere else the filtering result...:-) It looks obvious that he does not understand what AutoFilter means.

Comment: @FaneDuru  I agree with you.

Comment: FaneDuru,Gary's Student, Sir, i agree with both of you that filtering means altering/hiding rows, then please share that if i want to get that if Col"B" is >100 and less than 5000 then it should not disturb the other columns as Continue with current selection works for single column.

Comment: @ShSh  There are alternatives to `AutoFilter` that I will post **later today**

Comment: @ShSh  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Range("C2:C1000000", Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo=== Sir i was looking for this solution you helped me alot thank you so much, Please if possible add last Col range in my given code that i am unable to add in it, Range("C2:C1000000", Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

Comment: @ShSh  I do not understand..........Do you want to sort col **C** after the bad stuff gets removed ??

Comment: Sir Thank you so much for the help you provided but the question is closed, Thanks.